# prove that $f$ is total derivative if every $f_{i}$ is.

Tags: derivatives

I have this question: if $f:R^n \to R^m$ and $f(x)=(f_{1}(x),...,f_{m}(x))$ prove that $f$ has a total derivative at $a \iff f_{i}$ has a total derivative at $ a$.
I'm already stuck at the beginning.

Comment: That makes two of us: what does the sentence "$f$ is total derivative at $a$" mean?

Comment: there is a lineaire image $A:R^n->R^m$ so $f(x)=f(a)+A(x-a)+o(||x-a||) $ for $x->a$ . with the o- notation they mean : if f(x)=o(h(x)) that for every $\epsilon$ , is there a $\delta$ so that $||f(x)||$<$\epsilon$  h(x) for 0<||x-a||< $\delta$

Comment: Ah, ok. So you meant that "$f$ *has* a total derivative (i.e. it *is* differentiable) at $a$".

Comment: yes. Now you have to prove that for that notation $f_{i}$ has that too.

Answer (score 0):

Saying that a function $f:\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R^m$ is differentiable at $a$ means saying that there is a linear map $T:\Bbb R^n\to \Bbb R^m$ such that the function $\Delta^{f,T}_a(x)=\begin{cases}\frac{f(x)-f(a)-T(x-a)}{\lVert x-a\rVert}&\text{if }x\ne 0\\ 0&\text{if }x=a\end{cases}$ is continuous at $a$. Now, if we adopt your same notation $g(x)=(g_1(x),\cdots,g_m(x))$, you should remember that a function $g:\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R^m$ is continuous at $a$ if and only if, for all $i$, $g_i$ is continuos at $a$. Moreover, you'll notice that $(\Delta^{f,T}_a)_i=\Delta^{f_i, T_i}_a$.

This means that, if $f$ is differentiable at $a$ and $T$ is a suitable linear map, then $\Delta_a^{f_i,T_i}$ is continuous for all $i$, and therefore $f_i$ is differentaible at $a$. On the other hand, if all the $f_i$-s are differentiable and $G_1,\cdots, G_n$ are suitable linear maps that realise continuity in $a$ of $\Delta^{f_i,G_i}_a$, then the linear map $T(x)=(G_1(x),\cdots, G_n(x))$ realises continuity in $a$ of $\Delta^{f,T}_a$.